# Does beforeDestroy() calls on hard close of browser tab or window

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to cleanup some of the resources and cache on hard close of browser tab or window. To do same, expecting beforeDestroy() method of app.vue should be called.Correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened?

Comment: I tried it but it is not calling on hard close of tab

Comment: Does that not then answer your question?

Comment: I want to understand when beforeDestroy() of app.vue calls.If it is other components of beforeDestroy() then it is calling on switch of different components.

Comment: As you can see on the diagram [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks), it is called... _"when vm.$destroy() is called"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do a "hard close", the all JavaScript is ended. (With the exception of some service workers, which gets a bit complicated and seemingly out of scope of the question)

So your code in the `beforeDestroy` will not run.